# How to execute an runnable jar from java application

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have a runnable Jar which I want to invoke from my another java application. I have tried this solution

[link] [how to run a java executable jar in another java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700879/how-to-run-a-java-executable-jar-in-another-java-program)

I am able to execute the jar but seems that threads are in deadlock and it never generates the output. Can anyone please help me over this?

Comment: That is proper way as it is shown in link. Does that jar run properly if you run it separately?

Comment: Yes, if I run the Jar from a bat file, it works fine.

Comment: If I run the Jar from java program, jar runs fine. But at the end where it needs to generate the output, it stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) from plain Java or use library like [zt-exec](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec) from ZeroTurnaround. Second tools allows you to easily add for example execution timeout, set exit values, etc

In first case it'll looks like:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar myjar.jar").start();
p.start();
```

In second:

```
new ProcessExecutor().command("java -jar myjar.jar").execute();
```

Comment: I have tried this but it worked the same and application hangs.

Comment: By the application you mean executed jar or your application that is invoking execution?

Comment: It's my application which is invoking jar. Actually application doesn't get the control back from the JAR and it keep waiting. Moreover, I saw in debug window that there are two threads. Thread which is in the link I mentioned above and second is the DestroyVM thread. They never get the control.

Comment: I have used process executor now. Application is able to call the jar successfully. But seems that jar is throwing an exception of illegal method exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Integer.compare(II)I".

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you know the class which have `main` method, your program invoke the `main` method form jar.

Example.java

```
public void test() {
    String[] starr = <- if you have some parameter
    ProgramInJar.main(starr);
}
```

mytest.jar

```
public class ProgramInJar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // your operation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I have updated my JDK and then invoke the jar and it worked. Thank you all for the help and time.