# Auto Start Asterisk-Java Server in another class

Tags: java, multithreading

I need an asterisk server to start, whenever another main class is run of my project. To be more specific, I have a java server waiting for an xml file for the call info. If this file is received, the asterisk java.jar needs to be started automatically from the java server, so that the call can be handled.

Comment: Any code from what you have tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately I have nothing yet, but to make the question more understandable, all I need is code in a main class to do what the command line does here: java -jar asterisk-java.jar.

Comment: this automatically starts the main class of the asterisk-java.jar, which is the server.

Comment: here is another link which seems helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700879/how-to-run-a-java-executable-jar-in-another-java-program

Answer (score 0):

Have no any relation to asterisk.

Start new thread, in that thread start asterisk class code. Consult java threads documentation for more info.