# Executable Jar file does not work when run from Java code

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have run jar from cmd using
`java -jar abc.jar` It produces out put correctly on the command prompt window.

But when I try to run it from code, I am getting no out put, logs or exceptions;; and the program terminates.

So far, I have tried the following:  In both cases, input stream is not null but also contains no data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Process proc = null;
    try {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar path/to/abc.jar");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStream in =  proc.getInputStream();
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "path/to/abc.jar");
    pb.directory(new File("C:\\"));
    try {
        Process proc = pb.start();
        proc.getInputStream();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700879/how-to-run-a-java-executable-jar-in-another-java-program

Comment: You should also be checking the error stream. If the process produces errors, that's where they'll appear, not in the input stream. You should also do `proc.waitFor()` followed by checking `proc.exitValue()` - and add the result to your question. If it's non-zero, an error has occured.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the stuff it prints to System.out (including re-printing it on *your* System.out.) or System.err.