# How to see output on command prompt by running a jar/exe file?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, cmd, command-line-interface

I have created a jar which reads values from excel, does some manipulations and write the results back to excel.

When I run the jar, it works perfectly. I have also created an exe file for the jar and it works very well too.

However, while the values are being calculated for data on each row of the excel, I want the result to be displayed on command prompt too, for which i have syso statements.

I am able to achieve this by creating a batch file and running the jar through .bat file.
But when i run the exe file through a bat file, I'm not able to see the calculations on cmd.

Is there any way where I can see the calculated values in runtime through syso statements, on command prompt, just by double clicking on exe file?

PS: I do not want to run the jar through java -jar  command on cmd.
I want calculation results to be displayed on cmd if i just double click the jar/exe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15700931/235710

Comment: What tool are you using to convert the .jar into a .exe?

Comment: Are you ok with batch file? Is there any tool are you using for converting to exe file?

Comment: I'm using Launch 4j - https://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/launch4j-3/3.8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option on Launch4J to choose if the output should be displayed on console during runtime! I just selected it and the results are shown on console while running the exe file.

Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Noted down steps how to create a Runnable Jar file from eclipse tool. Oncle you done with below steps, you will get a runnable jar file. If you double click on the jar file, it will start executing your jar file through a command prompt.

- Create a batch file, and placed under any path in your system. In the example **"C:\Users\username\Desktop\test\my_script.bat"**

  ```
   @ECHO OFF
   set java_path=D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_41

   cd /d D:\rootFolder\extractData

   %java_path%\bin\java -jar yourJARfilename.jar 

   cmd /K

   EXIT /B 0
  ```

  - Create a java project.
  - Create a java a class for executing batch file. Specify your batch file path as coded below.

    ```
    package com.cmd.test;    
    import java.io.IOException;
    public class AutoExeJAR {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{    
            Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
             r.exec("cmd.exe /c start call C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\\test\\my_script");             
        }catch( IOException ex ){
            //Validate the case the file can't be accesed (not enought permissions)
     }}}
    ```
  - Right click on the above java project --> Export --> Runnable Jar -> (Select the above class file in Launch configuration dropdown in the popup window) -> Give the path for exporting as runnable jar file. **NOTE**: Selecting your class file name here is specifying invoking point soon after the jar file is double clicked.
  - Double click on that exported runnable jar file which executes the batch file automatically.
  - Please refer the [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/) as well.

Comment: So basically, I'm creating another jar to run the batch file which executes my actual jar file, correct?

Comment: Also, I do not want to hard code the path of bat file on my java code. Because it should work for any user, on any location.

Comment: Just throwing an idea. You can place executable jar file and bat file on the same folder. Then, find your current executable jar file path use below code sample. You can use a common file name for batch file like input.bat.                        **CodeSource codeSource = YourMainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
File jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
String jarDir = jarFile.getParentFile().getPath();                                      String batPath=jarDir+"\\input";** Use batPath string for executing under **r.exec(".......,"+batPath);**

Comment: r.exec("cmd.exe /c start call"+batPath);